# using webpack with dynamic requires to load sub-modules

Tags: webpack, date-fns

According to the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html#dynamic-requires) and the [date-fns module structure](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/tree/master/src/locale), I try to dynamically load a date-fns's locale module.

Without webpack, locale modules are loaded using `var fr = require('date-fns/locale/fr')`

With webpack, I try this without success:

```
var locale = 'fr';
var date = new Date();
var format = 'dddd DD MMMM YYYY';
var req = require.context('date-fns/locale', true, /^\.\//);
return df.format(date, format, { locale: req('./' + locale) });
```

the result is:
"Error: Cannot find module './fr'."

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct form is:

```
...
var req = require.context('date-fns/locale', true, /\.js$/);
return df.format(date, format, { locale: req('./'+locale+'/index.js') });
```

... or just

```
require('date-fns/locale/'+locale+'/index.js');
```